# What is the difference between (function(){})(); and (function(){}());?

Tags: javascript, function

Will the two following different lines of code do exactly the same?

```
(function(){})();

(function(){}());
```

Comment: Please add/tag the language you use.

Comment: The difference is that the first one ends with `)();` while the second one ends with `());`. What that difference means would depend on what language this is, which you didn't mention. :)

Comment: The language is JavaScript, as Jon Purdy already added. Thanks for that and also for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The only reason to include parentheses around the *whole* expression is to avoid its interpretation as a `function` declaration:

```
(function f(){}());  // (1) Expression
(function f(){})();  // (2) Expression
function f(){}       // Function declaration
function f(){}();    // Syntax error
```

But whether you invoke the function literal directly (1) or have an intervening pair of parentheses (2) makes no difference at all.